# Extending Exception class breaks getMessage()

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to build a child Exception class (`ovi_Exception`) and am running into issues with the __construct(). I want to also be able to access my MySQL class in the child Exception class and normally I do this by the following:

```
require_once( 'lib/Exception.php' );
$Process = new ovi_Exception( $MySQL );
```

`$MySQL` being an instance of the MySQL class. The exception class would then look like:

```
class ovi_Exception extends Exception {

private $MySQL = NULL;      

public function __construct( $MySQL ) {

    $this->MySQL = $MySQL;

}
```

Meaning I could now access the MySQL class as `$this->MySQL->method()`. However I know that to keep the Exception class working as normal I need to amend the `__construct()` as follows:

```
public function __construct( $MySQL ) {

    $this->MySQL = $MySQL;
    parent::__construct( $message, $code = 0 );

}
```

But now I get undefined variable notices and I can no longer retrieve `getMessage()` from the exception which is key to how I want to build this child class.

`parent::__construct( $message = NULL, $code = 0 );` removes the notice but I still get nothing from `getMessage()`. I don't really understand what this call to the parent `__construct()` is doing.

How can I maintain access to another class inside this child Exception class and keep the Exception class behaving as normal? Is the way I'm accessing other classes inside another fundamentally flawed? I've never had issues doing this before, but then am fairly new to OOP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why didn't you use a setter injection like:

```
class ovi_Exception extends Exception {
    private $MySQL = NULL; 
    public function setMysqlAdapter($MySQL) {
        $this->MySQL = $MySQL;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahaha almost at the same time! :D

Comment: @tftf yeah, it's often the case here in stackoverflow ^^.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is normal. You are creating a new class which extends an `Exception` class, but you are not passing the proper variables.

If you open the original `Exception` class you'll see

```
class Exception {
    ....
    public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)  {}
    ....
}
```

As you can see, the `Exception` class receives a couple of parameters (`$message,$code,$previous`) in it's constructor. In your `ovi_Exception`,which is extending the `Exception` class, you have only the database link variable `$MySQL`. Then you're initializing the parent class `Exception` and you're passing the empty/undefined variables `$message, $code = 0`. So it's quite normal you're getting **no** error message when you try `ovi_Exception->getMessage()`.